# a hibernate bug?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
16:59:08,082  INFO org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener:274 - Began transaction (1): transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager@f90137]; rollback [true]java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based!
at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:79)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:85)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:421)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:393)
at com.luck.dao.BaseDao$1.doInHibernate(BaseDao.java:106)
at com.luck.dao.BaseDao$1.doInHibernate(BaseDao.java:1)
```

and my code is :

```
public List<T> list(final String hql,final int start, final int limit,final Object ...args) {
    return hibernateTemplate.executeFind(new HibernateCallback<List<T>>() {
        public List<T> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            Query q = session.createQuery(hql).setFirstResult(start).setMaxResults(limit);
            if(args!=null&&args.length>0){
                for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                    q.setParameter(i+1, args[i]);
                }
            }
            return (List<T>) q.list();
        }

    });
}
```

the question is :
when I change  'q.setParameter(i+1, args[i]); to q.setParameter(i,args[i]),then It works .

```
public List<T> listJPA(final String hql,final int start, final int limit,final Object ...args) {
    return hibernateTemplate.executeFind(new HibernateCallback<List<T>>() {
        public List<T> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            javax.persistence.Query q = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().createQuery(hql).setFirstResult(start).setMaxResults(limit);
            if(args!=null&&args.length>0){
                for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                    q.setParameter(i+1, args[i]);
                }
            }
            return (List<T>) q.getResultList();
        }

    });
}
```

why? is that a bug in hibernate (3.3.2 GA and 3.5.2Final) or do I misunderstand what '1-base' 's means?

( the 1-based ordinal exception behaves differently in JPA)
then I remember the last project I create with JPA1.0,

I make anthoer demo,as the result,It works well

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based!
at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:79)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:85)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:421)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:393)
at com.luck.dao.BaseDao$2.doInHibernate(BaseDao.java:124)
at com.luck.dao.BaseDao$2.doInHibernate(BaseDao.java:1)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeFind(HibernateTemplate.java:343)
at com.luck.dao.BaseDao.list(BaseDao.java:119)
at com.luck.dao.HistoryDaoTest.testHistory(HistoryDaoTest.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
17:21:30,714  INFO org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener:294 - Rolled back transaction after test execution for test context [[TestContext@43ad4a testClass = HistoryDaoTest, testInstance = com.luck.dao.HistoryDaoTest@125d568, testMethod = testHistory@HistoryDaoTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@ddcd98 testClass = HistoryDaoTest, locations = '{classpath*:/application-context.xml}', classes = '{}', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader']]]



Hibernate: select history0_.bet_id as bet1_3_, history0_.bet as bet3_, history0_.num as num3_, history0_.time as time3_, history0_.type as type3_, history0_.win as win3_ from History history0_ where history0_.bet_id=? limit 
17:21:30,780  INFO org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext:1020 - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@102799c: startup date [Tue Feb 14 17:21:28 CST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
```

Comment: I edit it twice..... ..hard to format..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown the HQL, but in any case this message is misleading. Hibernate parameter starts from 0 in setParameter method as stated in the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29). And thats why it works when you use setParameter(i,arg[i]). Remember if the args and no of parameters are not same, you will also get this message, which probably wants to remind something about metadata but confuses the developer

Comment: er..the code is : dao.list("from History where id=?",0,1,20213)

Comment: as I said, message is misleading. Your q.setParameter(i,args[i]) is correct.

Comment: i wonder if so many ++ means accepted :)? if yes, plz tell the SO

Comment: aha,it means print :) len(++++++...) times :)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to find the question here :)

ordinal 1 based means that parameters start counting at 1 (not at 0). I usually tend to use the setParameter(String, Object) method to not rely on the order but on the name of query parameters.

So the answer is no, that is not a bug. It is probably mentioned in the JPA spec somewhere.

Comment: so the hibernate core should note it properly:'0-base' not 1-base